# Install Button on Live CD does not work

Tags: 18.04, live-cd, elementary, live-environment

Maybe this question is widely known by all of you and I am still too newbie / new to Linux to know this, but I am going to say it anyway.

Well, I am facing a problem while trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Gnome) on my laptop. Immediately before the live CD is completely loaded an error dialog box appears to the screen and the installer button stops working after the OS is completely loaded onto memory. The message is the one as follows:

> The installer encountered an unrecoverable error. A desktop session
>   will now be run so that you may investigate the problem or try
>   installing again

The same issue appeared when I tried to install on my machine other Ubuntu-like distros, such as: Linux Mint 19.1, Neon Linux, Elementary Juno and Ubuntu 18.04 Mate (which is much the same).

If you guys need any other information from my machine, do not hesitate to ask, but here is some basic ones about it:

`lspci`:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 18)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 06)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 06)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM57 Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 06)
12:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
13:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 02)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 05)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 05)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved (rev 05)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved (rev 05)
```

`lscpu`:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  2
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               37
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 450  @ 2.40GHz
Stepping:            5
CPU MHz:             2666.599
CPU max MHz:         2395.0000
CPU min MHz:         1197.0000
BogoMIPS:            4799.86
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-3
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid dtherm ida arat flush_l1d
```

fdisk filtering just the partition I am going to use Ubuntu:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l | grep sda12
/dev/sda12       974700544 1109063679  134363136  64.1G 83 Linux
```

Please, guys, do not ask me why I have an `sda12` on my machine, okay?

Now, what am I missing? what should I do to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance for any questions / answers or attempting to solve this head-breaking issue.

Comment: Please check integrity of your `.iso` files, (maybe) it was corrupted. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

Comment: When you boot you can check the integrity of the system media.  At the first person-in-circle & something-in-rectangle you hit a key and a menu appears, then select check-install-media.   Elementary & Mint are not Ubuntu and thus off-topic on this site.

Comment: I downloaded the same file twice and I got the same error.... I also checked the SHA1SUM file and was actually the same from the downloading page, but the MD5SUM was different. Do you think that something like that can happen?

Comment: how should I do that, Guiverc? I mean, that page is supposedly loading the distro files onto memory and it should not receive any user input at that moment...